# Simplifying an equation using a change of variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

Hi so I have the following question:

> (ii) Simplify the equation $$ (x+y)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - (x-y)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} =0 $$ using the change of variables  $u = \ln\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $v = \arctan (y/x)$.

This is part 2 of a question, part 1 asked me to find the total derivative and jacobian of $f(x,y,z)$, so I'm a bit confused as to how this leads on from that and I just don't really know where to begin so help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic curves satisfy the differential equations 
$$
\dot x=x+y\\
\dot y=-x+y
$$
which can be transformed to
$$
\frac{d}{ds}(e^{-s}x)=e^{-s}y\\
\frac{d}{ds}(e^{-s}y)=-e^{-s}x
$$
with the obvious solutions 
$$
x(s)=e^s(x_0\cos(s)-y_0\sin(s))\\
y(s)=e^s(y_0\cos(s)+x_0\sin(s))
$$
The change of variables corresponds to transforming these formulas into polar coordinates, which somewhat decouples these formulas.

---

To solve the given problem more along the given guidelines consider that the inverse transformation is 
$$
x=e^u\cos(v),\;y=e^u\sin(v).
$$
Consider the composite function 
$$
g(u,v)=f\bigl(e^u\cos(v),\;e^u\sin(v)\bigr)
$$
and compute its partial derivatives and how they are related in view of the PDE for $f$.

Comment: To be completely honest I don't have much of a clue what's going on because there's nothing in the lecture slides similar and I can't find any examples elsewhere but I think I sort of follow you

Answer (score 0):

This substitution is equivalent to [log-polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-polar_coordinates).

First, compute the partial derivatives

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}, \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{y}{x^2+y^2} $$
$$ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = -\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}, \quad \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} $$

Then use the multi-variable chain rule
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \dots $$
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = \dots $$

Now all you have to do is substitute, and make everything be in terms of $u$ and $v$